# MySQL Installer errors in the download process

Tags: mysql

Using windows 10 pro, i'm trying to install MySQL developer edition, but when it gets through the download process.
[image]

and these are the details:

```
1: Download of package 'MySQL Server 8.0.28' succeeded
2: Download of product 'workbench' started from https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQLGUITools/mysql-workbench-community-8.0.28-winx64.msi
3: Download of product 'mysql-visualstudio-plugin' started from https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQL-for-VisualStudio/mysql-for-visualstudio-1.2.10.msi
4: Download of product 'mysql-shell' started from https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQL-Shell/mysql-shell-8.0.28-windows-x86-64bit.msi
5: Download of product 'mysql-router' started from https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQL-Router/mysql-router-8.0.28-winx64.msi
6: Download of product 'connector-odbc' started from https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-ODBC/8.0/mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.28-winx64.msi
7: Download of product 'connector-cpp' started from https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-C++/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.28-winx64.msi
9: Download of product 'connector-net' started from https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-Net/mysql-connector-net-8.0.28.msi
10: Download of product 'connector-python' started from https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-8.0.28-windows-x86-64bit.msi
11: Download of product 'documents' started from https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQLInstaller/mysql-documents-8.0.28.msi
12: Download of product 'examples' started from https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQLInstaller/mysql-examples-8.0.28.msi
12: Download of package 'Samples and Examples 8.0.28' succeeded
9: Download of package 'Connector/NET 8.0.28' failed with message Bad download. Temp file removed. Please try again.
7: Download of package 'Connector/C++ 8.0.28' failed with message Bad download. Temp file removed. Please try again.
6: Download of package 'Connector/ODBC 8.0.28' failed with message Bad download. Temp file removed. Please try again.
2: Download of package 'MySQL Workbench 8.0.28' failed with message Bad download. Temp file removed. Please try again.
3: Download of package 'MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.10' failed with message Bad download. Temp file removed. Please try again.
10: Download of package 'Connector/Python 8.0.28' failed with message Bad download. Temp file removed. Please try again.
4: Download of package 'MySQL Shell 8.0.28' failed with message Bad download. Temp file removed. Please try again.
5: Download of package 'MySQL Router 8.0.28' succeeded
11: Download of package 'MySQL Documentation 8.0.28' succeeded
```

Any idea on how to overcome this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the source of the problem, but during the installation I selected the developer option which would install all resources available to developers.

My work-around was to start the install over again and select the option to only install the server.  that ran fine.

Then I ran the install again and selected the option to change or modify the installation.  I forget the exact wording but that was the concept.  at that point I had all the other features available to add such as workbench, odbc connector, documentation, etc...  This ran find and now all seems to be good.

I hope this helps someone.